# Mongoose: remove() returns true for already deleted items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

my code below returns *"User deleted"* even if the user was already deleted. I'd prefer to throw a **404** in this case, but I'd like to **query the DB as less as possible**.

Is there a way to get the `userNotFound` (see below) without manually checking if the user existed before deletion? Maybe I missed a feature of `remove()` or an alternative function.

```
var itemId = 123;
Item.remove({id: itemId}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Cannot remove item'});
    }

    // !!!
    if (userNotFound) {
        return res.status(404).json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }  
    // /!!!


    res.json({success: true, msg: 'User deleted.'});
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The feature you missed was actually checking the return value. You also accepted the wrong answer as the overhead of actually retrieving a document when you do not need to is something you should avoid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with the above approach is that `userNotFound` will always be `undefined` since you haven't defined it in the callback arguments. Better to use the **[`findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove)** function so that you can return the document removed if found:

```
var itemId = 123;
Item.findOneAndRemove({ id: itemId }) 
    .exec(function(err, item) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Cannot remove item'});
        }       
        if (!item) {
            return res.status(404).json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
        }  
        res.json({success: true, msg: 'User deleted.'});
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Mongoose's [`Query#remove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-remove) accepts a callback with 2 parameters:

1. `error`
2. `writeOpResult`

If you check the `writeOpResult` object, you should easily be able to tell whether deletion occurred or not.

It should contain a field called `nRemoved`. If it is `0` then no document was deleted, otherwise if it is a number then that many documents have been deleted. Similarly it has a field called `nMatched` which tells you how many documents matched your query.

So for your case it becomes like this:

```
var itemId = 123;

Item.remove({id: itemId}, function(error, writeOpResult) {

    if (error) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Cannot remove item'});
    }

    if (writeOpResult.nMatched === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }

    res.json({success: true, msg: 'User deleted.'});
});
```